# Setting class property is giving unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

Im very new to objective c and iOS. This is my first app ever so bear with me.

Im just trying to make a page with some buttons that are dynmically created from a text file, that will open a page in webview.

I'm basing my code off this: [how can i pass any kind of parameter in UiButton action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579603/how-can-i-pass-any-kind-of-parameter-in-uibutton-action)

**MyButton.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyButton : UIButton
{
    NSString *_linkURL;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *linkURL;
@end
```

**MyButton.m**

```
#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton
@synthesize linkURL = _linkURL;
@end
```

So then in my ViewController.m file I'm importing MyButton and trying to use it to create buttons that have the URL as their own property.

```
MyButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setLinkURL:URL]; //THIS IS THE LINE THATS GIVING ME THE unrecognized selector at instance error
```

Then I go on to get the URL in the buttonPressed method but I cant seem to get past this one error. I have no idea what Im doing wrong.

Comment: Is this a compile error or a runtime error? And you want `MyButton *button = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];`

Comment: Its a runtime error but that fixed it. Thanks I just didnt see that typo. Post as answer and ill accept if you want

Comment: First, get rid of the ivar declaration and the "@synthesize" line. No need to do either. If you create a property, linkURL, the compiler automatically creates the ivar _linkURL. Also, post the actual error, don't paraphrase.

Comment: You don't need the ivar anymore. You'll get the same result as before if you just have the property declaration. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632285/declaration-definition-of-variables-locations-in-objectivec/12632467#12632467) for more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
MyButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

It should be:

```
MyButton *button = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

As you had it you were creating an instance of `UIButton` instead of `MyButton`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with this line:

```
MyButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

You're casting a `UIButton` to a `MyButton`, but objects of type `UIButton` do not have the properties of a `MyButton` object. You need something like:

```
MyButton *button = [[MyButton alloc] initWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Comment: Yeah rmaddy mentioned that and it fixed it but it wasnt giving me a compile error or warning. That would have saved me about 30 minutes of my life

Comment: @Kierchon Right... The `buttonWithType` method returns type `id`, which can be cast to anything without a warning.